# jQuery (ajax) not executing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am creating an application where users can either create accounts via  username and password or just login by facebook.

I have the following function:

```
function myFunction(){
  jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "profile.php?uid=" + fb_id + "&fullname=" + full_name + "&username=" + username + "&isuser=" + isuser + "&limit=" + limit + "&imagedata=" + imgsrc + "&imagepath=" + filepath + "&submitted=1",
    success:function( msg ) {
     window.location.assign("profile.php?uid=" + fb_id + "&fullname=" + full_name + "&username=" + username + "&isuser=" + isuser + "&limit=" + limit);
    }
   });
}
```

Note: I don't need people to tell me that I am abusing URL "GET" parameters as I already know this, and it doesn't really matter in the long run due to the way the application will be packaged.

Is there a reason straight from the off that this function would not work?

When I log in to the application via Facebook the function seems to work perfectly. But when I am logging in as a user (with a username and password) it just refreshes the page & doesn't go to the url specified in the function.

I tried changing the 'window.location.assign' to go to a different URL, and nothing changed so it isn't even getting to the 'success:function(msg){' part.

The only difference between a Facebook user and a user who's logged in via username and password is the parameter values in the URL.

The following variables are assigned when a user is logged in via Facebook:  `fb_id`, `full_name`, `isuser`

The following variables are assigned when a user is logged in via Username & Password:  `username`, `isuser`

I am completely baffled. I realize that you guys would probably want a bit more info but I have troubleshooted everything myself right down to this function.

If anyone needs more info just tell me and I'll try.

Comment: If your success function isn't triggering in certain scenarios, it is most likely your server code that's crashing or throwing any other kind of error. Add an error function as well, and console.log the errormessage, see what that says when `success` doesnt trigger.

Comment: Sorry mate.  Get or Post? You mention get, but you are sending post? Thanks

Comment: *"When I log in to the application via Facebook the function seems to work perfectly. But when I am logging in as a user (with a username and password) it just refreshes the page & doesn't go to the url specified in the function."* to be clear, the current page is not profile.php correct? if that's the case, i don't see how what you're describing is possible unless some code elsewhere is interfering, such as a global ajax error handler.

Comment: To put it simply: the user uploads a photo from their device, the photo data in base64 is stored into a variable along with a path for it to be saved to. These variables are in Javascript and I need them to be PHP variables to save to the mysql database, so I use url parameters to $_GET the javascript variables into PHP, using the function above.

Comment: have you tried my suggestion at the answers section? If it haven't worked or if i have misunderstod the question, please, let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, you are saying GET, but your ajax implies POST.

Here's a POST Run:

```
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
})
  .done(function( msg ) {
    alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
  });
```

if you notice, data is part of the json construct:

If you change `method: "POST"` to `method:"GET"` and try that.  your URL call should work then.

Comment: This answer is along the right lines and is the one that inspired me to fix it by myself, so marking as most helpful. Instead of using GET like an idiot I just decided to have hidden input boxes and feed information through them to another page using POST. This way I don't run into "414 Request-URI too Large" errors either.

Comment: glad it worked.  I find the simpler issues are usually the most elusive and damaging.  Thanks for the approval.

Answer (score 0):

Try using **top.location.assign** instead of `window.location.assign`. I can't assure that this will work, but a similar problem has already happened to me and this solution worked like a charm.

Your code would look like this:

```
function myFunction(){
  jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "profile.php?uid=" + fb_id + "&fullname=" + full_name + "&username=" + username + "&isuser=" + isuser + "&limit=" + limit + "&imagedata=" + imgsrc + "&imagepath=" + filepath + "&submitted=1",
    success:function( msg ) {
     //The fix
     top.location.assign("profile.php?uid=" + fb_id + "&fullname=" + full_name + "&username=" + username + "&isuser=" + isuser + "&limit=" + limit);
    }
   });
}
```

## Explanation

Facebook apps runs inside a weird iframe logic that, mostly, doesn't allow you to access the topmost window object. Thats why you should, usually, use links with `target="_top"`.

This `top.location` is an alias to `window.top.location`, which is a reference to the topmost `window` object available in the window hierarchy.

Maybe this is your way to go.

Comment: This didn't work although I see where your logic is coming from. FYI Facebook only runs in that 'weird iframe logic' when authenticating a user for the first time, which brings up a page asking them to accept application permissions. Maybe I didn't write my question properly, I was VERY tired. Thanks for the help anyhow.